# Which SAGA versions does QGIS 2.18.10 support?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, saga

Beginning with QGIS 2.18.10 the `SagaAlgorithmProvider` do not longer have a dictionary called `supportedVersions`. Previously, it looked like this:

```
supportedVersions = {"2.1.2": ("2.1.2", SagaAlgorithm212),
                     "2.1.3": ("2.1.3", SagaAlgorithm213),
                     "2.1.4": ("2.1.4", SagaAlgorithm214),
                     "2.2.0": ("2.2.0", SagaAlgorithm214),
                     "2.2.1": ("2.2.0", SagaAlgorithm214),
                     "2.2.2": ("2.2.2", SagaAlgorithm214),
                     "2.2.3": ("2.2.3", SagaAlgorithm214),
                     "2.3.0": ("2.3.0", SagaAlgorithm230),
                     "2.3.1": ("2.3.0", SagaAlgorithm230)}
```

Now it simply says:

```
if not version.startswith('2.3.'):
  ProcessingLog.addToLog(ProcessingLog.LOG_ERROR,
                         self.tr('Problem with SAGA installation
                                  unsupported SAGA version found.'))
```

So I would assume that now only SAGA versions starting with 2.3 are supported. However, in my QGIS GUI the Log Messages Panel tells me that SAGA version 2.3.1 is not supported (interestingly, you can use SAGA 2.3.1 in a custom application like `RQGIS`). So which SAGA versions are supported in QGIS 2.18.10?

Answer (score 9):

Due to how complex it was to manage multiple versions (and how fast and erraticly the SAGA API changes), it was decided to support a single version. SAGA 2.3 is supposed to be something like an LTR, so API changes are not to be expected. Also, that's the version shipped with OSGEO4W.

any more info you can provide about the messages you see about your SAGA not being supported?

Comment: Yes, I do understand why you only want to support the SAGA LTR! The Log Messages Panel (QGIS 2.18.10) states `Problem with SAGA installation: installed SAGA version (2.3.1) is not supported` I am on a Linux Ubuntu 16.04 machine.