# SAGA not working under QGIS 2.18.10 (OSGeo4W)

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

Recently, saga algorithm disappeared from the processing panel. However, they are still listed under *processing->options*.

How to make them available again?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/245497/73883), from QGIS 2.18.10, only SAGA 2.3 is supported in QGIS.

However, in the OSGeo4W installer, the standard saga version is 2.1.2.2, whereas the LTR version is 2.3. [image: OSGeo4W installer]

By installing the LTR version instead of the normal one, the tools are back in the processing panel and usable both within QGIS and with python script.